# Custom line drawing in WPF

Tags: wpf, drawing, 2d

I'm trying to manually draw a line in WPF by overriding the OnRender method of a control and calling the DrawLine method on the given DrawingContext. I read somewhere that this method call doesn't instantly draw the line, but I can't work out how to actually cause the line to appear.

I've tried using a combination of PathGeometry, LineSegments, Line and Polyline controls. I could draw what I wanted then, but offsets weren't quite right (i.e. when drawing a line, it was fine, when drawing a polyline, everything became incorrectly offset).

Any advice on this would be great.

**EDIT**

*Pen Code*

```
    private static readonly Pen LinePen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green), 3.0d);
    private static readonly Pen WayPointPen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray), 3.0d);
```

*Render Code*

```
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        // Draw way points
        this.DrawWayPoints(drawingContext);

        if (mDrawing)
        {
            // Draw current line
            this.DrawCurrentLine(drawingContext);
        }
    }

    private void DrawCurrentLine(DrawingContext context)
    {
        if(mStartPoint.HasValue && mEndPoint.HasValue)
        {
            // Draw the line
            context.DrawLine(LinePen, mStartPoint.Value, mEndPoint.Value);
        }
    }

    private void DrawWayPoints(DrawingContext context)
    {
        if (mWayPoints.Count < 2)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Draw all points
        for (int i = 0; i < mWayPoints.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            var start = mWayPoints[i];
            var end = mWayPoints[i + 1];

            // Draw the line
            context.DrawLine(WayPointPen, start, end);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Test Project: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12763956/DrawingTest.zip
(Test Project written in Visual Studio 2010)

Usage:
 - Left click within the raised area to add points to the list.
 - Right click to end drawing and clear points.

Note: Custom drawn lines (in OnRender override) do not appear.

Comment: I draw lines with OnRender and they appear.  Can you add sample code so I can see what you're doing wrong?

Comment: I've added the render code I'm using. It's contained within a WPF control. I've tried having no content within the control and with a canvas element. I've also debugged to make sure the calls to DrawLine are actually hit, and they are.

Comment: Sorry for the delay answering -- was off on my motorcycle.  Your code looks perfectly fine.  Can you use Debug.WriteLine to get the specific points you are trying to draw lines to/from?  If they are out of bounds, no line will appear.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the values are within the bounds of the control, as I'm simply using the position of the mouse relative to the control whenever the left mouse button is clicked. The control has width 800 and height 480 and all clicks are registered within and give me positions within those bounds.

Comment: You still should add the Debug.WriteLine calls and check for 100% sure.  It's the only thing I can think of right now -- the code should work -- and I can't simulate your calls without the data you're using.

Comment: I've added a quickly made test project that reproduces my problem so that you can see my issue first hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two issues here. The first is your Canvas's Background covers up anything you'd draw on your DrawingControl. So if you set the Canvas Background to Transparent, you can temporarily work around that issue.

The second issue is you need to call [InvalidateVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatevisual.aspx) after you add a point to your collection to force it to redraw.

You would probably need to add another control that appears on top of the Canvas, and render the lines there. Or you'd need to render the Background yourself in the DrawingControl.OnRender method.

Comment: I have implemented those changes, but still no joy. I've updated the link if you wish to re-check the changes. I've also set a break point in the OnRender override to make sure it's actually being called.

Comment: @Slade - Make sure to do a `Rebuild All`. The changes didn't take affect right away for me either, until I did that. I added the InvalidateVisual call at the end of the AddPoint method. Will check your update though.

Comment: @Slade - This time the DrawingControl.Background is covering up the lines. You'd need to render that manually. Basically, you are rendering your UserControl, which has some child visualss as well as your content. One of the child visuals is a Border that renders the Background/BorderBrush. This still appears on top of the DrawingControl, even though it's in the ControlTemplate.

Comment: @Slade - To see what I mean, put a break point in OnRender. When it hits, add `this` into one of the Watch windows. Then click the magnifying glass on the right. Then drill down in the visual tree to see all the elements that appear on top of anything rendered by DrawingControl.

Comment: That's what my issue was! The background. Many thanks for that!